# setting tabwidth to 4 in git show / git diff

Tags: git, bash, tabs, whitespace, spaces

At work we are several developers and don't have a code style guide, and some developers indent with tabs, and some others with 4 spaces (luckily noone of the indent with spaces people uses different than 4 spaces). In general this is no (big) problem because in our editors we set `tabwidth=4` and all the indentation seems correct.

But in `git diff` or `git show` that's what appears:

```
diff --git a/mesclatabs.php b/mesclatabs.php
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..1986c91
--- /dev/null
+++ b/mesclatabs.php
@@ -0,0 +1,5 @@
+<?php
+function foo() {
+       echo "line with 1 tab\n";
+    echo "line with 4 spaces\n";
+}
```

The problem is `git diff` or `git show` where each tabs appears as wide as 8 spaces (well, in reality appears as a tab, and the shell (bash in my case) is showing the tab as 8 spaces. I suppose there must be some bash config to change this, but I'd like to know if git has an option to output tabs as 4 spaces in `diff` / `show`, as some developers work with `zsh` instead of `bash`.

Any ideas?

Comment: in an ideal world the devs would all use spaces and you won't have silly issues like this.

Comment: I completely disagree. Why would you represent something with 4 characters when you can represent it with 8?

Comment: Of course I don't know your situation, but I would really push for some super-basic coding guidelines, maybe just about the tabs/spaces.  No tabs sounds like a good idea, because then people tend to use tabs to align their comments and such, too, and it becomes a mess... And inserting tabs after spaces...  It's confusing when I go to edit and I can't see what's a tab and what's a space (so I always make tabs visible in my editor).  I'm a bit neurotic about it, though, so </opinion>

Comment: Also, I think it's possible to use (only) tabs consistently for indenting code, and spaces for any other alignment, and then people can change the tabstop to whatever they want.  I can't imagine people being consistent enough, though!

Comment: @MatthewG 8 sounds a lot grander than my 2... Thank you for showing me the light! :D

Answer (score 138, accepted):

I believe `git config --global core.pager 'less -x1,5'`

References:

- Original: (No longer valid) [git-scm chp7-1](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-1.html)
- Newer:

  - [git-config#git-config-corepager](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corepager)
  - [Customizing Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration)

Comment: The argument to less should be `-x5` because the +/- symbols of the unified diff don't impact the location of the tab-stop, but they *do* push all the spaces one character to the right. A tab-stop of 5 aligns everything properly.

Comment: yes, that works, setting `-x5` as CodeGnome said. Thank you both very much

Comment: urgh, it worked on just the first indentation level, at second, third, ... it does not align because of the initial + in the diffs. I'll leave at `-x4` as setting it higher misaligns it one char more for every indentation level (and also on non-added/removed lines is more consistent).

Comment: how to fix space in `git --color=always | less -r` ? `less -x1,5` is invalid

Comment: @ZhengKai: Just as a data point, I have `less` aliased as `less -R`, core.pager defined as above, and I run `git diff --color-words` -- everything works fine and the tab width is correct.  Maybe that helps?

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 14.04 - If I do this then the colouring escape sequences get shown instead of doing the colouring e.g.

ESC[1mdiff --git a/.gitignore b/.gitignoreESC[m
ESC[1mindex 6f4a9ba..4dc6e8d 100644ESC[m

Comment: When I do `git add -p` the pager is not used and the tab displayed in wrong way. If you describe how to fix this too. then the answer will be full

Comment: How to use this with `-r`, I want both `-r` and `-x1,5`, but `less -r -x1,5` does not behavior as expected.

Comment: @chenzhiwei: I've used `git config --global core.pager 'less -r -x1,4'` (3 space indent) and it works perfectly. (Note that GIT apparently sets the `LESS=-r` environ by default, but that shouldn't cause any issues in this case.)

Comment: @chenzhiwei - I haven't looked at this in many years from first answering, so I can't speak to the defaults back then. According to the documentation (edited to reference valid links) if `LESS` is unset Git sets it to FRX, otherwise if `LESS` is set, Git does not change it.

Comment: @IanRogers - For colour escape sequences you'd want to use `less -R` / `--RAW-CONTROL-CHARS` https://linux.die.net/man/1/less

Comment: For those wondering, in `-x1,5` the 1 is for the leading column in the diff output (that contains +, - and a space). Subsequent tabs then jump to columns 5, 9, 13, 17, etc - aka 1 + multiples of 4. So, for git diff the right argument is definitely `-x1,5`. People claiming above that `-x5` works for them ... well - that's a tab width of 5 spaces without a leading column, hmm. Unlikely?

Comment: `-x5` didn't work for me in the sense that it seems to have broken ANSI escape sequence processing -- `less` output started showing a lot of `ESC[31m-`, `ESC[m` and other similar sequences. Something to do with the `-` in the `-x5` -- `Rx5`, `-x1,5`, `Rx4` do not disrupt the ANSI escape sequence processing (regardless of their correctness). Furthermore, even with `R-x5`, subsequent tab stops are 5 characters apart, which seems to be definitely wrong.

Comment: Is there a way to make `less -x1,5` also work for git [combined diffs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#_combined_diff_format), which have N leading columns, where N is the number of parent commits?

Answer (score 7):

On MacOS you could do

```
$ git config --global core.pager 'less --tabs 4'
```

`-x/--tabs` is the same option I prefer to use full ones.
From `man less`

> -xn,... or --tabs=n,...
> Sets tab stops.  If only one n is specified, tab stops are  set  at
> multiples  of n.  If multiple values separated by commas are speci-
> fied, tab stops are set at those positions, and then continue  with
> the  same  spacing  as  the last two.  For example, -x9,17 will set
> tabs at positions 9, 17, 25, 33, etc.  The default for n is 8.

Answer (score 5):

As the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10584237/1850340 did not work for me because of my color settings I came up with following solution:

```
TAB=$'\t' && git config --global core.pager "sed 's/$TAB/    /g' | less" && unset TAB
```

This replaces all tab characters with 4 spaces before displaying it with less.
(The TAB workaround is needed to circumvent the shells backslash escape)

Comment: I'm not on something I can test with, but would this be where `less -R` would come into play? to allow the ANSI colour escape sequences through, opposed to `less -r`?