# How to change tab width in git diff?

Tags: git, whitespace, git-diff

The standard spacing for a tab is 8 characters.

I prefer to view that as 4 characters in my editors and console. I can easily change this default behavior on console with the `tabs` command:

```
tabs -4
```

However, when using `git diff` or `git show` it displays in the default 8 character tab whitespace.

How can I get `git diff` to render tabs as 4 character spaces?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with `git diff`.

git diff actually renders a tab, which is later converted by your terminal emulators (for instance, `gnome-terminal`) to *spaces*.

Go to the preference of your terminal emulator to change that setting.

---

Also, git may use a pager, so you might want to configure it like that:

```
git config --global core.pager 'less -x1,5'
```

More information here: [setting tabwidth to 4 in git show / git diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581093/setting-tabwidth-to-4-in-git-show-git-diff)

Comment: Hmm, my terminal is set to 4... This just doesn't appear the same in `git diff` So if I `cat file` then tabs are 4 chars, but `git diff file` they are instead 8.

Comment: Nice, I see your edit. It is the pager, thanks! Will accept in 6 more minutes...

Comment: For eventual use, `export LESS=Rx4` can be useful instead of changing the global Git configuration.

Comment: How can it be converted by the terminal emulator and yet changing of the behaviour is done in... `less`? If `less` output a tab, which is then converted by the terminal emulator, then there would be no need to change settings for `less` specifically?